# Start regex from the last occurrence of a tag

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm trying to identify `bbcodes` inside texts using REGEX.

I have the following text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [color] consectetur adipisicing el it labore et [color=red]dolore magna aliqua[/color] minim veniam.
```

And currently I'm using this pattern:

```
/\[([a-z0-9]+).+?\[\/\1\]/i
```

But it catches this:

```
[color] consectetur adipisicing el it labore et [color=red]dolore magna aliqua[/color]
```

instead of this:

```
[color=red]dolore magna aliqua[/color]
```

I'm thinking of two solutions, but I don't know how to make it work:

1. Not allowing tags inside tag content. Then, `[b]this [b] won't be allowed[/b]`;
2. Starting the pattern from the last tag occurrence.

Thanks for helping,

JG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex finds the leftmost occurrence of `[` followed by the BBtag, and then `.+?` matches any 1+ chars other than line break as few as possible, but as many as necessary to find the leftmost `[/<CLOSE_TAG>]`.

You need to make sure you do not match the opening tag on the way to the closing one:

```
\[([a-z0-9]+)[^\[]*(?:\[(?!\1\b)[^\[]*)*?\[\/\1\]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UJgXO6/2)

It is almost the same as [`\[([a-z0-9]+)(?:(?!\[\1\b).)+?\[\/\1\]`](https://regex101.com/r/YDysms/1) that might be a bit more readable, but is less efficient.

**Details**:

- `\[` - an open bracket
- `([a-z0-9]+)` - Group 1 (tag name): 1+ alphanumeric symbols
- `[^\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`
- `(?:\[(?!\1\b)[^\[]*)*?` - 0+ sequences (as few as possible) matching

  - `\[(?!\1\b)` - a `[` not followed with Group 1 text as a whole word
  - `[^\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`
- `\[` - a `[`
- `\/` -  a `/`
- `\1` - Group 1 text
- `\]` - a `]`.

Comment: WOW! Many thanks! It worked perfectly! I was trying to find a case it's not working but I could not find anyone :-) Awesome! Thanks!